# Store JSON as a field in PostgreSQL with Spring Data JPA

Tags: json, spring, postgresql, jpa-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I want to have a specific table with two columns, an ID and a field in which I'll store a JSON object. And I'm using Spring Data JPA.

I'm thinking of something in this line, but I'm not sure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
public class SomeTable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    private UUID id;

    // getters and setters for id here..

    // here to be the field for storing JSON objects and it's getters and setters
}
```

Comment: In general, if possible, you should try to avoid storing json in postgres ... it's bad design.

Comment: Well, they have a JSON datatype (I think planned for pg 9.2) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/datatype-json.html I get your concern, it's a bad practise, but I have a special use case for this one table and I'd like to have it like that :)

Comment: So what is your question exactly? You can simply store the json as a string and you're done. The postgres data type does not do any more than ensuring the string is valid json

Comment: +1 With the release of PostgresSQL 9.2, I'm interested in this too.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what version of PostgreSQL you are using.  If you are using 9.1, check out https://bitbucket.org/adunstan/json_91 which gives you the same functionality you'd get in 9.2.  If it is an older version you are going to have to go with text or backport that module.